# C++ operator overloading >= with 2 different returns

Tags: c++, return, operator-overloading

I've got a class which looks like this:

```
class Player
{
    friend bool operator>=(Player &pl1, Player &pl2)
    {

        return true;
    };
private:
    int nr, height, weight;
}
```

A player has a number, height and weight.
Now I'd like to know if Player1 is bigger and/or heavier than Player2. After this I'd like to print it out like this:

```
Player A is 2 cm bigger (smaller) and 7 kg heavier (lighter) than Player B.
```

How can I manage it when I can only return true or false? I can return true when he's bigger and heavier or false when he's smaller and lighter, but how should I manage the bigger/lighter | smaller/heavier case?

EDIT: I HAVE TO DO IT WITH `operator>=`. This is an exam for my school and the condition is to do it like this. Here's the text:

> After the input the players will be displayed. By using operator overloading >= will be checked if the player is bigger 
>   and/or heavier than the other player. The result with the determined data will be displayed, e.g.: Player A is 2 cm bigger (smaller) and 7 kg heavier (lighter) than Player B.

Comment: Maybe use a custom enum ...?

Comment: Well... what would you expect? Is a player that is smaller but heavier `>` or `<` a player that is bigger but lighter? I don't think operator overloading is the best way to go in this case.

Comment: You should simply define an extra method that has the appropriate return types. There is no need to fit everything into the standard operators and overload them. Don't take OOP as a cult.

Comment: This is an exam I have to do for school and the condition is to use the operator overloading >=. How does an enum help me?

Comment: Look for difference of the two?

Comment: @Maxzeroedge I don't quite get what you mean?

Comment: Is the class definition yours or is it part of the question?

Comment: @Rudi your edit with the problem statement gives really important information. It's now possible to solve it which previously wasn't.

Comment: @mark It's my class definition, I've written it by myself (it's the shorter version, only the necessary parts are here in the code)

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl So what's the solution if it's solvable now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you organize your class differently, perhaps you can do something like the following:

```
class PlayerWeight {
private:
    int weight;
public:
    int getWeight() const {
        return weight;
    }
    bool operator >=( const PlayerWeight &playerWeight ) {
        return weight >= playerWeight.getWeight();
    }
    PlayerWeight( int weight ) : weight( weight ) {
    }
};

class PlayerHeight {
private:
    int height;
public:
    int getHeight() const {
        return height;
    }
    bool operator >=( const PlayerHeight &playerHeight ) {
        return height >= playerHeight.getHeight();
    }
    PlayerHeight( int height ) : height( height ) {
    }
};

class Player : public PlayerHeight, public PlayerWeight {
public:
    PlayerHeight& height() {
        return *this;
    }
    PlayerWeight& weight() {
        return *this;
    }
    Player( int height, int weight ) : PlayerHeight( height ), PlayerWeight( weight ) {
    }
};

int main( int argc, char**argv ) {
    Player playerA( 72, 180 ), playerB( 74, 160 );
    // comparison
    std::cout << "Player A is " << ( (PlayerHeight)playerA >= playerB ? "bigger" : "smaller" ) << " and " << ( (PlayerWeight)playerA >= playerB ? "heavier" : "lighter" ) << std::endl;
    // or...
    std::cout << "Player A is " << ( playerA.height() >= playerB ? "bigger" : "smaller" ) << " and " << ( playerA.weight() >= playerB ? "heavier" : "lighter" ) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If a strict ordering doesn't exist for your classes, don't define ordering operators.

Instead, you could write functions like `heightDifference` and `weightDifference`:

```
int heightDifference (const Player& a, const Player& b)
{
    return a.height - b.height;
}
```

You can then use those functions to work out the information you need.

Comment: I also would have done it with functions (it's way easier), but this is an exam I have to do for school and the condition is to use the operator overloading >=.

Comment: Does the problem statement give you required semantics for the operator overload? Perhaps it means it should return `true` if *both* attributes are `>=` the other? However, that would mean your comparison would be asymmetrical, which is not nice.

Comment: I've added the text of the exam in my 1 post. I'v translated it from german into english, so I hope it's understandable.

Comment: I'd ask for clarification as the problem seems a bit odd. What's the point in overloading a comparison operator if you're going to be calculating the difference between them anyway?

Comment: Yes, I've asked the question in a forum of my group. I hope I get a fast response from my teacher and/or studens. Otherwise it's a really odd approach to solve the problem like this. There must be some mistake or I don't really understand the question correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try a typical approach of optimization problems.

When you have multiple (conflicting) objectives you can try taking a scalar aggregation/projection of their values.

I.e. you have two distinct objectives: maximize weight and height (`>=` could be interpreted as a *awe-inspiring* operator!):

```
double impressive(int height, int weight)
{
  return height + ratio * weight;  // some good ratio

  // lexicographic ordering induced by very large/small values of ratio.
}

bool operator>=(Player &a, Player &b)
{
  return impressive(a.height, a.weight) >= impressive(b.height, b.weight);
};
```

It all depends on the semantics of the operator.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a function for comparison that return `std::pair` with one of them giving you the difference of height and the other will give you difference of weight.

```
using namespace std;
pair<int,int> compare(Player &a, Player &b)
{
    return make_pair(a.height-b.height, a.weight-b.weight);
}
```

At last you can compare your results by simply putting `if-else` to whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with order operators (`<=`) is that ordinary mortals use them as a full order relation : antisymetric, reflexive and transitive and defined for every couple. If any of these 4 rules is not true **do not use** `<=`.

If you need a total order compatible with your requirement (or at least not contrary to it), my advise would be :

- if A if (strictly) bigger than B then B <= A (in fact B < A)
- if A is same size as B, and A is heavier than (or same weight as) B then B <= A
- else A <= B (in fact A < B)

That means that you combine your two order relations with one taking precedence.